# NSNotification message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotification

FirstController.m

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

    NSNotification *msg = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"addNevItem" object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",1]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:msg];

}
```

TwoController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(addNevItem:)
                                             name:@"addNevItem"
                                           object:nil];
}

-(void)addNevItem:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"dd");

}
```

If the action is performed once, in the console I see one message. If the action is performed two times, in the console I see two more. If the action is performed three times, in the console I see three more. Why is this happening? I use the same code in other parts of the program and there is always only one message.

Comment: It looks as if you mixed up the selector and the name in the `addObserver` call. Is that you real code? - And where is the observer removed?

Comment: "If the action is performed once, in the console I see one message": I can't see your question here, this is exactly the intended behavior. You send one notification, you receive one notification per observer. You send two, you receive two. What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you post a notification every time the action is executed so naturally you get just as much notifications

BUT

You have forgotten (or not shown ;)) to call removeObserver so notifications might 'pile up' (every living VC gets the notification)